# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'rgbkymc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
train_class = train_df['Class'].value_counts().sortlevel()
my_colors = 'rgbkymc'  #red, green, blue, black, etc.
train_class.plot(kind='bar', color=my_colors)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I'm getting:

```
Value Error : Invalid RGBA argument : 'rgbkymc'
```

I can't get the reason why I'm getting this error as I have checked everything and it seems fine.

Can anyone help me identify the error, please?

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
131     try:
--> 132         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
133     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.

KeyError: ('rgbkymc', None)
```

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for the `colormap` argument instead?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Dataframe.plot()` doesn't actually *take a `color` argument*. You'd have to drive a [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) call directly if you wanted to use a simple sequence of colours (but note that there are better options, listed below).

If you do decide to use `matplotlib.pyplot.bar()` directly, then take into account that it's `color` argument then only takes either a *single [valid color value](https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html)*, so `'r'` or `'k'`, or a *sequence* of such color values (the [documentation for `bar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar) calls it *array like*). A *list* of names would work:

```
my_colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'y', 'm', 'c']  # red, green, blue, black, etc.

plt.bar(len(train_class), train_class, color=my_colors)
```

The documentation states that the sequence should be equal in length to the number of bars plotted:

> The optional arguments *color*, *edgecolor*, *linewidth*, *xerr*, and *yerr* can be either scalars or sequences of length equal to the number of bars.

However, it is just easier to pass in a *color map* to `Dataframe.plot()` here. [Color maps](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) as a handy and fast path towards distinct bar colors. You can pass one in as the `colormap` keyword argument, this can be a named map (as a string):

```
train_class.plot(kind='bar', colormap='Paired')
```

or an actual matplotlib colormap object from the `matplotlib.cm` module:

```
from matplotlib import cm

train_class.plot(kind='bar', colormap=cm.Paired)
```

If you wanted to stick with `matplotlib.pyplot.bar()`, but use a colormap, then create your series of colors from a colormap. Pandas uses `np.linspace()` for this so here we do too:

```
import numpy as np

paired_colors = cm.Paired(np.linspace(0, 1, num=len(train_class))
plt.bar(len(train_class), train_class, color=paired_colors)
```

For bar plots, I'd pick a [qualitative colormap](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html#id21); each name is an attribute of the `cm` colormap module. In the above, `cm.Paired` is a one such color map. Calling the color map with a sequence of floats between 0.0 and 1.0 gives you back colours picked at each 'percentage' of the range. You could also pass in a sequence of integers to index individual colours instead.

Circling back to Pandas, you can create a colormap from a hand-picked sequence of colours too, with a [`matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap` instance](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap):

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

my_colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'y', 'm', 'c']  # red, green, blue, black, etc.
my_colormap = ListedColormap(my_colors)
```

and then pass that to your dataframe `.plot()` call:

```
train_class.plot(kind='bar', colormap=my_colormap)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the update, but however i tried that and i made my colors list `[(0.57999999999999996, 0.57999999999999996, 0.57999999999999996), (0.628, 0.628, 0.628), (0.628, 0.628, 0.628)...]` and more  and i do `color=colors` in the pandas `plot` function but it gives me all black bars...

Comment: @U10-Forward: actually, I am misreading comments and getting things confused. `DataFrame.plot` doesn't take a `colors` argument. At all. Only a colormap is supported. Sorry about that, a commenter here confused me and threw me off.

Comment: @U10-Forward: right, answer re-written to actually answer both the question correctly and your situation.

Comment: Some of my values are zero so i get `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0.0`

Comment: @U10-Forward: `0.0` is not a [valid color specification](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colors.html); if `0.0` is supposed to be black then  you could use `(0., 0,. 0.)`, `(0., 0., 0., 0.)`,  `'#000000'`, `'#00000000'`, `'k'`, `'black'`, `xkcd:black` or `'0.0'` (the latter is a string, not a float).

Comment: Unfortunately when my color list is `['0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.04', '0.58', '0.628', '0.628', '0.644', '0.668', '0.688', '0.688', '0.696', '0.696', '0.708', '0.728', '0.732']` it still produces all black bars

Comment: This is my code: `colors = ListedColormap([str((i*4) / 100) for i in df['11/11'].replace(0, 1)])`
next line is:
`ax = df[df.columns[1:]].plot(kind='barh', fontsize=18, legend=None, colormap=colors)`

Comment: @U10-Forward: I'd expect those to be gray levels, as per *a string representation of a float value in [0, 1] inclusive for gray level (e.g., '0.5');*. Sorry, this is all getting a little too detailed for comments, perhaps you need to post this as a question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024320/listedcolormap-list-results-in-all-black-bars-matplotlib

Answer (score 6):

The question needs a slight modification as it would first raise the following error:

```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sortlevel'```

This is because [sortlevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html) is deprecated since version 0.20.0. You should instead use [sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index) in its place.

Plus, the letters symbolising the colors in the `color` parameter of the `plot` command need to be provided in a *list* and not in a *string*. You can read more about it on [Specifying Colors](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colors.html) on [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib).

Hence, you can use this code:

```
train_class = train_df['Class'].value_counts().sort_index()
my_colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'y', 'm', 'c']  #red, green, blue, black, 'yellow', 'magenta' & 'cyan'
train_class.plot(kind = 'bar', color = my_colors)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'y', 'm', 'c']  #red, green, blue, black, 'yellow', 'magenta' & 'cyan'
train_class_distribution.plot(kind='bar',color=my_colors)
```