# `ListedColormap` list results in all black bars - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I would like to output a plot that which controls darkness (or lightness) by the value, so example: value of 20 would be a darker color and value of 5 would be a lighter color, but I would as want the same numbers to have the same colors (and easy to see...), so far I tried `ListedColormap` (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802475/valueerror-invalid-rgba-argument-rgbkymc/50802773#50802773)) which only got me as far as all black bars, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 13]})
colors = ListedColormap([str((i*4) / 100) for i in df['values'].replace(0, 1)])
df.plot(kind='barh', colormap=colors)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If bar plots worked with colormaps, you would need to specify something to map from. But since they don't anyways, you will need to supply a list of colors, just like everyone else does in the answers to questions on that topic.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So i would need to type in the colors manually?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The values are unknown so what should i do?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What you think would be the most optional solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to supply a list of colors. Here, using matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 13]})
colors = [str((i*4) / 100) for i in df['values'].replace(0, 1)]
plt.barh(df.index, df['values'].values, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I actually tried this before just not with `plt.barh` didn't realize it is needed!